# AngularJS project structure and defintions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In app.js file I defined the following:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

In testController.js I defined the following:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope'], function($scope) {
    $scope.temp1 = "";
    $scope.temp2 = -1;
});
```

In testService.js I defined the following:

```
app.factory('testService', function ($http, $scope) {
    'use strict';
    return {        
        list: function (callback) {
            $http.get('url?param=' + $scope.temp1).success(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

In testController.js and testService.js lint tells me that app is undefined. How can I tell both of the files that app is the app from app.js?

How can I tell testService.js that $scope.temp1 is actually taken from testController.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all of your code should be wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#iife

```
(function(){
    real code goes here
})();
```

This keeps the global variable space clean

To access app from the other code, you don't.. you retrieve it again.  So your controller would look like this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module("app").controller("testController", ....
})();
```

And finally, the controller part of your code has misplaced brackets.  The closing ] should be after the function.

```
(function(){
    angular.module("app").controller("testController", ['$scope',function($scope){
        // function code here
    }]
})();
```

And your service is a singleton (there is only one for the whole app.  So, you would not pass scope to the constructor as you have, but you would pass it to the function that needed access to it.

But passing scope down to a service like that will probably tightly couple your controller to your service which is something you shouldn't be doing.  You should be retrieving from the service and passing specific elements in that it needs rather than the scope that could change.

Comment: Wrapping in an IIFE makes totally no difference if you're using `angular.module('app')`. `angular` is already in global scope and for the rest there's nothing being declared so you might as well leave that out.

Comment: Thanks. So if I need to retrieve app again for every object, what is the use of the "lonely" app.js? So instead of using $scope.temp1 inside the service, I should pass it as a parameter to its function and use that parameter? can you point me to an example of such calling to a service?

Comment: The lonely app.js is just to define the module and define dependencies that might exist at the application level.  Lazy programmers put all of the dependencies there, but you really should declare those as far down the hierarchy as possible.

Yes, you are correct, pass temp as a parameter.

change your list function to take the callback and the temp parameter

Comment: Best practice? Says who? Please refer the so called ninja who sold you that nonsense. Maybe it's best practice in your book, not in mine. It only clutters the code, readability goes down, adds an extra function call and it has absolutely no use or function in this case so why use it? An IIFE has loads of valid/good usecases and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @DaveBush, I understand that, I meant calling of such function, I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @Amos, I'm not sure what you are asking for.  Once you inject the service  in your controller, you should be able to call the list function hanging off the object you are returning.